# Make text flow downwards rather than upwards?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make these icons with just CSS (except for the white icon). The problem I'm running into is that if my icon's name exceeds the width and starts wrapping the text starts overlapping the image (as it is shifted upwards, as seen on the second element), what I need to have the text do is shift downwards (as shown on the third element).

[image]

Here is my html:

```
 <div class=circle><label>Manage Queries</label></div>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
.circle
 {
  float:left;
  position:relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px; 
  background: #C70C11 url('myimage.png') no-repeat center center;
  }

  .circle > label
  {
    font-family:arial;
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: -20px; 
    text-align:center;
    width:inherit;
  }
```

I have tried `vertical-align` but I haven't found any success with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `bottom:-20px`, try `top:100%`

Here is a proof of concept: http://jsfiddle.net/eZcRk/

Answer (score 1):

Just set the `top` property of the `label` to the height of the `div`

```
.circle > label
{
    top: 128px; 
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/u6hJN/)

Answer (score 0):

To get `vertical-align` to work, you need to set the parent tag to have `display: table`. Then you set the tag with these properties:

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: bottom;
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried setting vertical-algin:bottom; and display:inline; for your label ?